# Remove "margin" around <input> in jQuery Mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

jQuery Mobile automaticly adds this to an < input >. How can I override it and remove the top margin from the div?

`<div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
<input id="myinput">
</div>`

And css of the div looks like:

```
.ui-input-text input, .ui-input-search input, textarea.ui-input-text {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
display: block;
line-height: 1.4em;
outline: 0 none;
padding: 0.4em;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: `.ui-input-text #myinput {margin-top:0;}` will overwrite the ui style for that input

Comment: @Pete Doesn't work. Only affects the "input" field, and not the surrounding div

Comment: Your question states that you want to remove the margin from the top of the input field?  And the styles you have shown are for the input field

Comment: @Pete it's because the "margin" is the div, and jQuery Mobile adds it automaticly.

Comment: try `div.ui-input-text { padding-top:0; }` (or margin-top if it's actually margin and not padding)

Comment: @Pete that worked, but can I also target a specific id/class of inputs?

Comment: you would need to put your own class / id onto the div to target it, at the moment it is just using the bootstrap added classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsz28/)**

You may write new CSS for input with parent containers class name so that it will take higher priority

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
    <input id="myinput" />
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap .ui-input-text input{
    border:1px solid red; /*desired style*/
    margin-top:0;
}
```

Comment: I can alter the input, but it's the child div that adds the padding... tried to change to "div" instead of "input" but didn't do anything

Comment: I had to use !important, to override the margin. Works now :-)

Answer (score 0):

Starting with jqm 1.4 you should use `class="ui-field-contain"` instead of `data-role="fieldcontain"` around your `<label>` and `<input>` tags. To adjust the vertical spacing of each of the field sets you can override the margins of the `<div>` tag using a simple additional style property:

```
<div class="ui-field-contain" style="margin-top:2px;margin-bottom:2px;">
  <label for="field1">Field label:</label>
  <input type="text" name="field1" data-mini="true" id="field1" />
<div>
```